# Serializing object result in Json with backslashes

Tags: vb.net

I have a class as follows:

```
 Public Class Directdownline
        Public Property plid As String
        Public Property firstname As String
        Public Property lastname As String
        Public Property email As String
        Public Property phone As String
        Public Property policiessold As Integer
        Public Property downlineagents As Integer
    End Class
```

Which I populate this way

```
                Dim Agent As New List(Of Directdownline)
                Do While RS.Read
                    Agent.Add(New Directdownline() With {.plid = RS(0), .firstname = RS(1), .lastname = RS(2), .email = RS(3), .phone = RS(4), .policiessold = RS(5), .downlineagents = RS(6)})
                Loop
                Dim jsonData As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Agent)
                AngularPayload.Property("businessdata").AddAfterSelf(New JProperty("directdownline", jsonData))
```

And I am adding the array with Newtonsoft to a current Json on the last line, right after the property "businessdata". This works, but the problem is that the result is having a backslash at jsonData. I tried adding Agent, jsonData.toString() etc and nothing seems to work.

```
 "directdownline": "[{\"plid\":\"2\",\"firstname\":\"Marianela\",\"lastname\":\"thompson\",\"email\":\"test@test.com\",\"phone\":\"(213) 123-1231\",\"policiessold\":0,\"downlineagents\":0},{\"plid\":\"3\",\"firstname\":\"Louis\",\"lastname\":\"Hamilton\",\"email\":\"louis@hamilton.com\",\"phone\":\"(213) 123-1231\",\"policiessold\":0,\"downlineagents\":0}]"
```

Plus NewtonSoft is adding the array between "" instead of the array.

Then I figured I could use JArray instead of JProperty

```
AngularPayload.Property("businessdata").AddAfterSelf(New JArray("directdownline", jsonData))
```

But I get the error System.ArgumentException: Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where's `businessdata` coming from? Anyways, not knowing where that comes from, have a look at this https://dotnetfiddle.net/hwZy5l it may be helpful.

Comment: On another note, there's other ways this could be accomplished if you'd include all relevant code for us to see.

Comment: It comes from a Json stored a AngularPayload. I will check your fiddle. Thanks Codexer.

Comment: Can you include what this looks like and expected results?

Comment: So, businessdata is a property on an existing Json, and you want to add another property called directdownline right below it? Because that the purpose of AddAfterSelf, but it is to add a property. Do you have access to the Json you are loading at AngularPayload? If so, create the property directdownline and fill it out inside the loop.

Comment: Codexer is right, can you include your json?

Comment: Yes, I want to add the property right next to businessdata. I do have access to the JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the backslash cause you are SerializingObject an object. This can be solved with something like

```
Dim jsonData As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Agent)
Dim MyObject = JToken.Parse(jsonData)
```

And since you said u have access to modify the Json Object, if you add the empty array "directdownline":

```
{
    "success": "1",
    "type": "individual",
    "status": "1",
    "userdata": {
        "firstname": "Jane",
        "middlename": "B",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "dob": "11/13/1976 12:00:00 AM",
        "address": "1billing 23 street",
        "address2": "",
        "city": "billing city",
        "state": "MN",
        "zip": "90210",
        "cellphone": "(777) 777-7777",
        "emailaddress": "test@test.com"
    },
    "businessdata": {
        "domicilestate": "AL",
        "legalname": "Jane Doe",
        "owners": "",
        "authorizedperson": {
            "firstname": "",
            "lastname": "",
            "email": "",
            "phone": ""
        }
    },
    "directdownline": []
}
```

Then you can

```
 Dim item As JArray = CType(AngularPayload("directdownline"), JArray)
Do While RS.Read
        Agent = New Directdownline() With {.plid = RS(0), .firstname = RS(1), .lastname = RS(2), .email = RS(3), .phone = RS(4), .policiessold = RS(5), .downlineagents = RS(6)}
        Dim jsonData As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Agent)
        Dim MyObject = JToken.Parse(jsonData)
        item.Add(MyObject)
    Loop
```

Then you will be adding to the array.

Comment: I tried it, but how should I declare item?

Comment: I missed it, you are right. Dim item As JArray = CType(AngularPayload("directdonwline"), JArray) I will edit the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the JSON

```
{
    "success": "1",
    "type": "individual",
    "status": "1",
    "userdata": {
        "firstname": "Jane",
        "middlename": "B",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "dob": "11/13/1976 12:00:00 AM",
        "address": "1billing 23 street",
        "address2": "",
        "city": "billing city",
        "state": "MN",
        "zip": "90210",
        "cellphone": "(777) 777-7777",
        "emailaddress": "test@test.com"
    },
    "businessdata": {
        "domicilestate": "AL",
        "legalname": "Jane Doe",
        "owners": "",
        "authorizedperson": {
            "firstname": "",
            "lastname": "",
            "email": "",
            "phone": ""
        }
    }
}
```